# Java indexOf method as a short cut to manual search

Tags: java

I've got the following Java code but List.indexOf() seems to do pretty much the same thing (including returning -1 if not found. Is there any way of passing indexOf() an Object that expresses the idea that the object is not 0?

```
/**
 * Find the first non-zero element in a List of Integers
 * @param row List of Integers
 * @return -1 if all zeros in row
 * otherwise position of first non zero element
 */
public static int leading(List<Integer> row) {

 for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
   if (row.get(i)!= 0) {
      return i;
   }
 }

 return -1;
}
```

Re: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: If I passed in null into IndexOf() it will always return -1 because my list always contains Integers. I want to do something like row.indexOf(Integer a where !a.equals(0)). Not sure if possible

Comment: not 0?  You mean `null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `List.indexOf` "solution"

[`List.indexOf(Object o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) is defined as follows:

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or `-1` if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index `i` such that
>
> ```
> (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))
> ```
>
> is `true`, or `-1` if there is no such index.

It is tempting to try to give a "meta" element object that is not really in the `List`, and may not even be of the same type as the actual elements of the `List`, and yet is `equals` to some desired element based on a predicate. This should work, since `indexOf` is defined in terms of the given `Object o`'s `equals` method against an element in the list (and not the other way around), but is a really "hacky" way of achieving what you want.

Here's a proof of concept:

```
// PROOF OF CONCEPT ONLY! DO NOT IMITATE!
// abusing indexOf(Object) to find index of a negative integer in List

List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(3,4,5,-6,7);
Object equalsNegativeInteger = new Object() {
    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof Integer) && ((Integer) o) < 0;
    }
};
System.out.println(nums.indexOf(equalsNegativeInteger));
// prints 3
```

The "meta" element object is `equals` to any negative `Integer`, and yet no `Integer` can ever be `equals` to it. This asymmetry is a gross violation of [the `equals` contract](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), but it "works" nonetheless.

---

#### Guava solution

A much better solution that conveys the intent is using Guava's higher-order functions. Here's one from [`com.google.commons.collect.Iterables`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html):

> [`<T> int indexOf(Iterable<T> iterable, Predicate<? super T> predicate)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29)
>
> Returns the index in iterable of the first element that satisfies the provided predicate, or `-1` if the `Iterable` has no such elements. More formally, returns the lowest index `i` such that:
>
> ```
>  predicate.apply(Iterables.get(iterable, i))
> ```
>
> is `true`, or `-1` if there is no such index.

#### Snippet

Here's a snippet to illustrate the expressive power of Guava's higher-order functions:

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import com.google.common.base.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IterablesPredicateExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,-8);
        Predicate<Integer> isNegative = new Predicate<Integer>() {
            @Override public boolean apply(Integer n) {
                return n < 0;
            }
        };          
        // Get index of first negative number
        System.out.println(Iterables.indexOf(nums, isNegative));
        // 2

        // Find that number
        System.out.println(Iterables.find(nums, isNegative));
        // -3

        // Find all negative numbers
        System.out.println(Iterables.filter(nums, isNegative));
        // [-3, -5, -7, -8]

        // Are all numbers negative?
        System.out.println(Iterables.all(nums, isNegative));
        // false

        // Find all non-negative numbers
        System.out.println(Iterables.filter(nums, Predicates.not(isNegative)));
        // [1, 2, 4, 6]
    }
}
```

---

#### Summary

- `List.indexOf(Object)` can be abused to find elements that satisfy a given predicate, but this is a violation the `equals` contract
- Using Guava's [`Predicate`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and higher-order functions like `indexOf`, `find`, `filter`, `all`, `any` etc allows you to express these operations in a much more powerfully expressive ways

Comment: +1, the use of predicates would definitely be a good way to expression the intent of the code.

Comment: @coobird: Just don't downvote me for the proof-of-concept "hack" part =) I'm just showing that it's definitely not impossible to do with `List.indexOf(Object)` alone (but you probably wouldn't want to do it that way with Guava alternative).

Comment: The hack (+1 for pointing out that it is a hack) may only work if the list implementation calls `equalsNegativeInteger.equals(e)` instead of `e.equals(equalsNegativeInteger)`, because that equals method is not symetric. +1 anyway for the predicate approach.

Comment: @Willi: the documentation does say that "formally" it's `o.equals(e)` and not the other way around, but I'm not sure how strongly adhered this contract is. Ultimately, if a `List` implementation violates this `indexOf` contract by using `e.equals(o)` instead and the hack fails, you can't complaint because you violated the `equals` contract first.

Answer (score 1):

The [`List.indexOf(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) method will return the first index at which the specified `Object` is found.

The code that is given in the question appears to have the following requirements:

- Return the first index at which `0` is *not* found in the list.
- If no such element exists in the list, return `-1`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to express the above using the `indexOf` method.

Therefore, the code you've presented seems to be an acceptable implementation for the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

No, java doesn't support closures.

The standard workaround is using an anonymous inner class, but that requires enough boilerplate code to render the solution just a complex as implementing that loop.

Answer (score -1):

I do not believe such a method exists in the standard runtime library.

Question is whether you need this so much that it pays off to keep track of the not-zero values, or you can do with a brute force search.  I would do with the latter, and keep track of the difference between System.currentMillis() and if it goes over a limit decided by you, log it.  Then you don't have to run a profiler to locate a known possible bottleneck.

Also note you do autoboxing in your sample.  That overhead may be unneccesary.